# Does Google Maps have an onZoomLevelChange() or similar?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to place different drawables on the map depending on the zoom level. Can this be done? IS there a way to detect zoom change when it happens?

Android App

Comment: I ended up finding the answer.

Here is an extension for the `MapView` called `mapview-overlay-manager`

http://code.google.com/p/mapview-overlay-manager/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the Maps API you can just call the "getZoomLevel()" on the [MapView](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html).

```
 int    getMaxZoomLevel() 
          Returns the maximum zoom level for the point currently at the center.
 int    getZoomLevel() 
          Returns the current zoom level of the map
```

The easiest way to handle it would be overwrite the "OnTouchEvent" to check and dispatch a background task associated with the zoom level.

```
boolean onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent ev) 
          Passes trackball events to the overlays first, and if they don't handle them, feed it to a gesture detector, and dispatch the detected gestures
```

make sure you supply "super.OnTouchEvent" if you don't do anything special with it.

Comment: This seems like a useful but round about way of doing one. Great Thanks